# Trouble Loading Audio Clips with Buttons for a Sound Board

Tags: javascript, arrays, button, audio, p5.js

https://editor.p5js.org/hvgrajciar/full/KIOn1sX6h

I am having problems getting these audio files to work with my soundboard map. I want to attach each audio file to its corresponding button on the map, but each time I load in another audio file it messes up the other audio files and the buttons they are attached to.

For example, I'll press the first audio button after I've loaded in the second audio file in preload and the first audio button will start playing the second audio file instead of the first. This occurs even though I've tried my best to declare the buttons as variables that attach to functions that will play the correct audio file when the button is pressed.

This is my first assignment with p5js and I feel like I'm really close but I'm missing something major.

```js
var scotland;
let mySound;
var button1;
var button2;
var button3;
var button4;
var button5;
var button6;

function preload() {
  scotland = createImg("https://i.redd.it/czyk6caeln921.png");
  mySound = loadSound("audio/1clip.ogg");
  mySound2 = loadSound("audio/2clip.mp3");
  mySound3 = loadSound("audio/3clip.mp3");
  mySound4 = loadSound("audio/4clip.mp3");
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(700, 900);
  button1 = createButton("Shetland");
  button1.position(600, 100);
  button2 = createButton("Glasgow");
  button2.position(320, 730);
  button3 = createButton("Aberdeen");
  button3.position(540, 520);
  button4 = createButton("Isle of Lewis");
  button4.position(200, 380);
  button5 = createButton("The Scottish Borders");
  button5.position(400, 800);
  button6 = createButton("Argyll");
  button6.position(290, 620);
  button7 = createButton("Ross Sutherland");
  button7.position(320, 400);

  // Header Text for Map
  var div = createDiv("");

  div.html("Scottish Regions and Accents");
  div.position(60, 80);
  div.style("font-size", "32px");
  div.style("textStyle", "Impact");
}

function mousePressed(button1) {
  if (mySound.isPlaying()) {
    // .isPlaying() returns a boolean
    mySound.stop();
  } else {
    mySound.play();
  }
}

function mousePressed(button2) {
  if (mySound2.isPlaying()) {
    // .isPlaying() returns a boolean
    song.stop();
  } else {
    mySound2.play();
  }
}

function mousePressed(button3) {
  if (mySound3.isPlaying()) {
    // .isPlaying() returns a boolean
    mySound3.stop();
  } else {
    mySound3.play();
  }
}

function mousePressed(button4) {
  if (mySound4.isPlaying()) {
    // .isPlaying() returns a boolean
    mySound4.stop();
  } else {
    mySound4.play();
  }
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  scotland.position(0, 0);
  scotland.size(700, 950);
}
```

Comment: You might want to look into arrays and loops.

Comment: Thank You for some advice to help me in the right direction.

Comment: `function mousePressed(button4) {` doesn't do what you think it does--the `mousePressed` function is re-declared over and over and the parameters are unused variables, not something that tells p5 which button you're adding the handler to, so only the last one registers. It's not specific to any button. rather, it triggers when the mouse pressed anywhere. Try `button1.mousePressed(() => {/* handle sound 1 changes */});`.

Comment: You also have `song.stop();` but there's no `song` variable in your code. I suggest formatting your code with https://prettier.io/playground/ as you work--I did the first one for you.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments, [`function mousePressed() {}`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/mousePressed) is a global function, not a per-button handler. The parameter name doesn't attach it as a handler to that button variable as you may think.

The correct approach to attach a listener to a specific element is calling [`Element.mouseClicked(handlerFunc)`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Element/mouseClicked) (or `mousePressed`).

Although it's not the primary issue, your code would be improved quite a bit by using an array of objects containing the raw data for the buttons rather than a bunch of loose variables. The power of the array comes alive when you loop over its elements to apply the same logic to each one, reducing code repetition.

Also, `noLoop()` is useful since there isn't any animation in your app (yet), so you needn't burn cycles rerendering the same map image over and over 60 times a second.

I used random wikimedia commons clips as audio placeholders in the example below. You should use your original files here.

```js
const buttons = [
  {text: "Shetland", x: 600, y: 100, clip: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/22/30_second_sample_of_Agnus_Dei_by_Ernesto_Herrera%2C_performed_by_BYU_Singers.ogg"},
  {text: "Glasgow", x: 320, y: 730, clip: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/d/d3/Aphex_Twin%2C_Green_Calx%2C_1992.ogg"},
  {text: "Aberdeen", x: 540, y: 520, clip: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/8/8a/AphexTwin4.ogg"},
  {text: "Isle of Lewis", x: 200, y: 300, clip: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/7d/Aphex_Twin_-_XMAS_EVET10_sample.ogg"},
  {text: "The Scottish Borders", x: 400, y: 800, clip: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/9/9b/Excerpt_of_F%C3%BCnf_geistliche_Lieder_f%C3%BCr_Sopran_und_f%C3%BCnf_Instrumente%2C_Op._15%2C_V._Fahr_hin%2C_o_Seel%2C_zu_deinem_Gott%3B_Anton_Webern%2C_composer%2C_1917%3B_Peter_Rosegger%2C_poet%2C_1900%3B_and_Halina_Lukomska%2C_soprano_and_Pierre_Boulez%2C_conductor%2C_1969.ogg"},
  {text: "Argyll", x: 290, y: 620, clip: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/8/81/Messiaen-ascension-3-latry.ogg"},
  {text: "Ross Sutherland", x: 320, y: 400, clip: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/d/d5/Messiaen-livre-7-soixante.ogg"},
];
let scotland;

function preload() {
  buttons.forEach(e => {
    e.clip = loadSound(e.clip);
  });
  scotland = createImg(
    "https://i.redd.it/czyk6caeln921.png",
    "Image of Scotland"
  );
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(700, 900);
  buttons.forEach(e => {
    e.button = createButton(e.text);
    e.button.position(e.x, e.y);
    e.button.mouseClicked(() => {
      e.clip.isPlaying() ? e.clip.stop() : e.clip.play();
    });
  });

  // Header Text for Map
  const d = createDiv("Scottish Regions and Accents");
  d.position(60, 80);
  d.style("font-size", "32px");
  d.style("textStyle", "Impact");

  scotland.position(0, 0);
  scotland.size(700, 950);

  noLoop();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
```